# Looping throuh json

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

I'am trying to add json data to the lists. 
Json looks like this:

```
[{'genus': 'Musa', 'name': 'Banana', 'id': 1, 'family': 'Musaceae', 'order': 'Zingiberales', 'nutritions': {'carbohydrates': 22, 'protein': 1, 'fat': 0.2, 'calories': 96, 'sugar': 17.2}}]
```

But with my function, i can append to lists only those objects:

```
genus': 'Musa', 'name': 'Banana', 'id': 1, 'family': 'Musaceae', 'order': 'Zingiberales'
```

Can't get anything from 'nutritions'. 
Adding code:

```
import requests
import json


name = []
id = []
family = []
genus = []
order = []
carbohydrates = []
protein = []
fat = []
calories = []
sugar = []

def scrape_all_fruits():
    data_list = []
    try:
        for ID in range(1, 10):
            url = f'https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/{ID}'
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.json()
            data_list.append(data)
    except:
        pass
    return data_list


def listify(fruit_stats):
    alist = json.dumps(scrape_all_fruits())
    jsonSTr = json.loads(alist)
    for i in jsonSTr:
        try:
            name.append(i['name'])
            id.append(i['id'])
            family.append(i['family'])
            genus.append(i['genus'])
            order.append(i['order'])
            carbohydrates.append(i['carbohydrates'])
            protein.append(i['protein'])
            # fat.append(i['fat'])
            calories.append(i['calories'])
            sugar.append(i['sugar'])
            for nutrs in i:
                fat.append(nutrs.a['fat'])
        except:
            pass
    return fruit_stats


print(listify(fat))
```

Can anyone explain to me what iam doing wrong ? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

jsonSTr in your code is a dictionary. By default looping over a dictionary returns its keys.

You can fix this by either looking up via the key you receive:

`name.append(jsonSTr[i]["name"])`

or by looping over the values:

`for i in jsonSTr.values():`

if you need both the key and the value you can use the `items()` method.

Comment: Well, if i do print(type(jsonSTr)) i've got, that is a list.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, your code is too complicated. If you have a nested dictionary, you can flatten it with a special function (example from [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-flatten-a-dictionary-in-python-in-4-different-ways/)).

```py
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
import pandas as pd
import json

def flatten_dict(d: MutableMapping, sep: str= ".") -> MutableMapping:
    [flat_dict] = pd.json_normalize(d, sep=sep).to_dict(orient="records")
    return flat_dict

Data = []
test_response = '[{"genus": "Musa", "name": "Banana", "id": 1, "family": "Musaceae", "order": "Zingiberales", "nutritions": {"carbohydrates": 22, "protein": 1, "fat": 0.2, "calories": 96, "sugar": 17.2}}]'
ResponseJSON = json.loads(test_response)
Data.append(flatten_dict(ResponseJSON[0]))
print(json.dumps(Data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "genus": "Musa",
        "name": "Banana",
        "id": 1,
        "family": "Musaceae",
        "order": "Zingiberales",
        "nutritions.carbohydrates": 22,
        "nutritions.protein": 1,
        "nutritions.fat": 0.2,
        "nutritions.calories": 96,
        "nutritions.sugar": 17.2
    }
]
```

What to do further, is up to you, but the output structure is good for pandas tables, which can be easily manipulated:

```py
Table = pd.DataFrame(Data)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i need to append those values from dict to seperate lists.

Comment: @Dab you can turn every `pandas.DataFrame` column into list, actually. For example, `Table['genus'].tolist()`.